# How to add user entered URLs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

I have a `textField` and `textView` that I need user entered URLs to be `hyperlinked` (I.E) when a user enters a website address it becomes clickable which takes you to that website, I have found plenty of articles on how to embed links just not on how to code for the user entered web addresses. (if it matters I'm using `coreData`) I have selected detect links in the `xib` but it that doesn't work. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextView can only do that via data detectors and even there the links are the original text and you have no control over the user leaving the app.

The easiest method to get links fully under your control is to use the UI classes from DTCoreText. Those have buttons for the links which you can do anything you like with.

https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText